# minecraft using skins on a family account

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I downloaded minecraft on my account on my xbox and bought a skin for my daughter.  I have since created her own login in our family account and wonder if there is a way to use the skins that i bought under my login for her login.

Comment: Should probably check, are you talking about an **Xbox One** or an **Xbox 360?**

Answer (score 1):

## Bad News

This is not possible, sorry.

## Good News

It is under review on the [Minecraft Feedback Website](https://feedback.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/community/posts/360009527631--Feature-Request-Purchased-Content-Sharing), so we might see this in the future!